# Web page divided into two clickable buttons/links, horizontal to one another

Tags: jquery, html, css

The issue I am having is that I have a web page that should be divided into two large div links like buttons, one on the right and one on the left placed horizontally to one another. The buttons should take up half the screen each. There is also a header and footer on the page. I am using css table to try and achieve this. However I'm having so many issues trying to get it to look the way I want.

If one button has more text in it it will stretch across the screen and buttons will no longer be equal size. If I try and use table-layout:fixed the screen does split in half the way I want but the text will not move to the center of the button/div and the whole div is no longer a link, just the text.

For it to look the way I want it I need two large div links that fill the screen between the header and the footer that are equally the same size, one to the left and one to the right where the text is centered in the block and the amount of text doesn't affect the size. Also need it to work in all browsers, but if thats not possible just chrome is ok.

Here is my solution so far below.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id = 'menuChoiceContainer'>
        <div id='menuChoiceHeader'>
                <h1>
                    Management Tool
                </h1>
        </div>
            <a href="/tool/itool/index.php" id="choicelink1">
                <span id="link-spanner1">MODELS1</span>
            </a>
            <a href="/tool/ytool/index.php" id="choicelink2">
                <span id="link-spanner2">MODELS2</span>
            </a>
        <div id='menuChoiceFooterWrapper'>
            <div id='menuChoiceFooter'>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>

#menuChoiceContainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    display: table;
}

#choicelink1{
    font: normal 5.10em/150px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#choicelink2{
    font: normal 5.10em/150px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%; 
    display: table-cell;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning to put one anchor to the left and other to the right

HTML

```
<div id='menuChoiceContainer'>
  <div id='menuChoiceHeader'>
    <h1>Management Tool</h1>
  </div>
  <a href="/tool/itool/index.php" class="option" id="choicelink1">
    <span id="link-spanner1">MODELS1</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/tool/ytool/index.php" class="option" id="choicelink2">
    <span id="link-spanner2">MODELS2</span>
  </a>
  <div id='menuChoiceFooterWrapper'>
    <div id='menuChoiceFooter'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
} 
#menuChoiceHeader {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.option {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.option span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#choicelink1 {
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;

  font: normal 5.10em/150px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#choicelink2 {
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;

  font: normal 5.10em/150px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/c3oLmapf/)

You could also take a look at [bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) using which it is very easy to create any (even responsive) web page layout.

Comment: Hi this is great and really helped me out, only thing I added was vw for font size resizing instead of em/px and it worked just the way I wanted it to, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically table-cell is equal to td tag in the table. Lots of people having problem in changing the size of the table-cell.

By creating a display as table and table-cell you making things complex.

I would suggest you to use display:flex. This is the easier way to do this. By declaring display:flex in parent tag, the tags inside the parent will be aligned in the horizontal manner. By using id you can give your desired width to a tag.

In the giving example i equally divided the space of parent.
Here 100% is shared as 25% for 4 tags.
Otherwise you can give width individually to the child elements.

Make sure sum of child width is not more than parent. If exceeds, will not work properly
Example: menuchoice-100%=header-10%,choicelink1-40%,choicelink2-40%,footer-10%

I Hope this works.

HTML :

```
   <div id = 'menuChoiceContainer'>

    <div class=child id='menuChoiceHeader'>
    cool
    </div>
        <a class=child href="/tool/itool/index.php" id="choicelink1">
            <span id="link-spanner1">MODELS1</span>
        </a>
        <a class=child href="/tool/ytool/index.php" id="choicelink2">
            <span id="link-spanner2">MODELS2asdasdasdasd</span>
        </a>

    <div class=child id='menuChoiceFooterWrapper'>
        <div id='menuChoiceFooter'>
        cool
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS :

```
#menuChoiceContainer {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-width: 1000px;
display:flex;
}

.child
{
width:25%;
border:1px solid red;
}

#choicelink1{
font: normal 5.10em/150px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
position:relative;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right center;
background-color: #fff;
}

#choicelink2{
font: normal 5.10em/150px 'Capital TT', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
position:relative;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
background-image: url(../images/menuchoiceverticalsplit.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #fff;
text-wrap:normal;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi tried this out but all the text disappeared off the page and it wasn't formatting correctly, thanks for the answer though!